# Prevent sleep while Word is open

Tags: windows-10

I'm currently running Word/Caffeine batch to prevent sleep, but opening multiple docs also opens multiple instances of Caffeine and it gets tedious manually closing them.

Is there a batch that can prevent sleep when Word (or any programme) is running and reverts to default sleep when closed?

Comment: Your power management options. Not automatic but easily scriptable.

Comment: You can use power pan to make your PC not sleep. It is the easiest solution. You can refer to this : https://www.dell.com/support/article/sg/en/sgdhs1/sln297929/change-sleep-settings-or-create-modify-a-power-plan-in-windows-10?lang=en

Comment: If I may say so both answers concerning power plan/management are completely useless, as it does not address the issue (my question), that is, how to automate open Word docs and no sleep. I might as well stick to Caffeine if I have to mess about changing power plans every time I open Word. 

I say again: a batch which allows for sleep to be suspended when a Word doc is open, and resumes normal or default sleep when a Word doc is closed

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 64-bit.

How to write a one line Windows shortcut, or a cmd batch file to change your power settings (display timeout, sleep timeout, hard disk timeout, ...), open any program, and restore your original power settings when you close the program.

Power timeouts are between 1 minute and 9999999 minutes.

The four most common AC/DC power settings:

- `monitor-timeout-ac 10 monitor-timeout-dc 10`
- `disk-timeout-ac 20 disk-timeout-dc 20`
- `standby-timeout-ac 30 standby-timeout-dc 30`
- `hibernate-timeout-ac 30 hibernate-timeout-dc 30`

You don't need a batch file. You can do it with a windows shortcut. I like 30 minutes as my default timeout for sleep. I like to start shortcuts like this minimized. See pic at bottom. Change your path to your program.  This shortcut can be run with or without admin privileges. Do not start your program like this: `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE.lnk"`

On a desktop:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 1440 &"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE" &POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 30
```

On a laptop both AC and DC:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 1440 &POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-DC 1440 &"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE" &POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 30 &POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-DC 30
```

This will change the sleep timeout to 24 hours, open your program and if you open your program this way will wait until you close your program to restore the sleep timeout to 30 minutes.

If you want a batch file:

On a desktop:

```
@title Change power settings, open program, restore power settings
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions
rem change timeout from 1 - 9999999 minutes
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 1440
rem do not use:
rem start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE.lnk"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE"
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 30
exit /b
```

On a laptop both AC and DC:

```
@title Change power settings, open program, restore power settings
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions
rem change timeout from 1 - 9999999 minutes
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 1440
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-DC 1440
rem do not use:
rem start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE.LNK"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE"
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 30
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-DC 30
exit /b
```

[How to change Windows 10 power settings from the command line](https://ss64.com/nt/powercfg.html)

[Powercfg examples](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powercfg+examples)

Shortcut to Power Control Panel:

```
C:\Windows\System32\control.exe powercfg.cpl,,23
```

For more info from cmd:

```
powercfg /change /?
```

Run minimized:

[image: screenshot run minimized]

How to customize your power settings for any program you want to run with a windows shortcut or a cmd batch file.
Disable screen shut off for specific software. Enable screen shut off for specific software. Disable sleep for specific software. Enable sleep for specific software. Disable disk sleep for specific software.  Enable disk sleep for specific software.